# Rails json return with jbuilder html tags

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, twitter-bootstrap

On my controller I return json with `index.json.jbuilder`.

On the controller part, I have an array which stores the extras as;

```
..
@ti << ('&bull; ' + e.name + ': ' + price)
..
```

Then in the jbuilder part I have;

```
..
json.obligatory_body @ti.join("<br>")
..
```

I am trying to show these elements with a bullet with line breaks inside bootstrap popover.

Inside the popover this is how it looks like;

```
<a tabindex="0" class="pull-right color-red " role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="left" title="" data-content="• Fuel: 95 €<br>• Service: 100 € " data-original-title="">Details <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Here `data-content` shows correctly but on the screen I see `<br>` tag as well instead of the line break.

Answer (score 1):

Rails escapes the html tags by default. Try the following:

```
json.obligatory_body @ti.join("<br>").html_safe
```